# IMemberIdentifier missing from TypeLite.TsModels namespace

Tags: typelite

So I've been using TypeLite 1.0.1 with good results until I upgraded to the latest version (1.1.0). It seems the IMemberIdentifier interface is gone, which broke this part of my T4 script:

```
ts.WithFormatter((TypeLite.TsModels.IMemberIdentifier identifier) => 
        Char.ToLower(identifier.Name[0]) + identifier.Name.Substring(1));
```

I was using this to camel case all my properties in the TypeScript interfaces I'm generating. I can't seem to find a workaround for it and the TypeLite [site documentation](http://type.litesolutions.net/Tutorials/Customization) still uses the above code in their example. I had the same problem with version 1.0.2.

Any comments or ideas much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that method of formatting members has changed.
To camel case all properties use:

```
ts.WithMemberFormatter((TypeLite.TsModels.TsProperty identifier) => Char.ToLower(identifier.Name[0]) + identifier.Name.Substring(1));
```

Comment: It doesn't work for names like _GMTAdjustment_ or _IPAddress_